# What's the right code to include a legend in my Python map for threat categories of SPC convective outlook using Matplotlib panel plot?

Tags: python, metpy

I've written a code to plot an SPC convective outlook.  I have the map created, cities, states, lakes, etc., that I want on there.  I also want to put a legend for the map as well outlining the different threat categories (i.e. 1: marginal, 2: slight ....).  I have the actual legend created using matplotlib patches.  What code should be written to get the legend onto the map with everything else? This is what I have right now:

[image]

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pgreen_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='palegreen', label='General T-Storm')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='1: Marginal')
yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow', label='2: Slight')
brown_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='3: Enhanced')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='4: Moderate')
magenta_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='magenta', label='5: High')

panel = MapPanel()
panel.title = 'SPC Day 1 Convective Outlook May 24, 2023'
panel.plots = [city_geo, cat_geo]
panel.area = [-130, -65, 23, 50]
panel.projection = 'mer'
panel.layers = ['lakes', 'land', 'ocean', 'states', 'coastline', 'borders']

plt.legend(handles=[pgreen_patch, green_patch, yellow_patch, brown_patch, red_patch, magenta_patch], loc=(.08,.2))

pc = PanelContainer()
pc.size = (12, 10)
pc.panels = [panel]
pc.show()
```

Comment: Hey, how did you create the map? (or is it just an image where you want to put the map on top)

Comment: I created the map by using a geojson file fromm the SPC website.  Then creating the plot geometry of the SPC outlook, inputting the city locations via a US cities .zip file and putting those on top of the SPC outlook.  The "panel_plots" line in the code above is how I created the two plots. I'm trying to put the legend above onto the panel of the map below.

Comment: thx, I actually meant what library you used since the import for the `MapPanel` function was missing (and I overlooked that you already tagged your question with `metpy`).  I added an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you use matplotlib functions with `plt. ...` (e.g. `plt.plot(...), plt.legend(...), ...` they will try to infer the last used plot-axis and if this is not possible a new one will be created.

For more info on this, have a look at the matplotlib-docs, specifically the section on [application interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces).

- In sort, to make sure that your features end up on the right axes, explicitly target the axes you want to use.
- I have no experience with MetPy, but from the docs of [MapPanel](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.plots.MapPanel.html) you should get the axes object of the map via `panel.ax`

Putting all of this together, changing `plt.legend(...)` to `panel.ax.legend(...)` should do the job.

Comment: Hm ... that gave me an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'figure'

Comment: ? that does not make sense... are you sure this is related to the `panel.ax.legend()` call?  can you post the traceback where the error originates from?

Comment: Here is the traceback ... 
      6 panel.layers = ['lakes', 'land', 'ocean', 'states', 'coastline', 'borders']
      7 
----> 8 panel.ax.legend
     9 
     10 pc = PanelContainer()

/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/plots/declarative.py in ax(self)
    426         # map projection.
    427         if getattr(self, '_ax', None) is None:
--> 428             self._ax = self.parent.figure.add_subplot(*self.layout, projection=self._proj_obj)
    429 
    430         return self._ax

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'figure'

Comment: OK, as I see it this is an issue with metpy itself... it seems that their "declarative plotting interface" delays the initialization of the figure until it is effectively drawn?? and as a consequence `panel.figure` is still None at the time you need it... there are certainly ways around this (maybe use the interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) and call `panel.ax.legend()` after `plt.show()` .. not sure... )  I think it's worth taking this up with the metpy devs on [github](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues) since I have no experience with the internals of their package.

Comment: After defining your `PanelContainer`, you can call `panel.draw()` on the individual `MapPanel` or `pc.draw()` on the `PanelContainer`, and then this `panel.ax.legend()` solution will work. This is still worth opening a GitHub issue or discussion about labels, legends, and other fine-grained control in declarative, though the project usually tries to steer people back to direct matplotlib usage for that.